# Launch OSRM server on large area

Tags: openstreetmap, osrm

in the tutorial it is shown how to start an OSRM server with this example :

```
wget http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/germany/berlin-latest.osm.pbf

osrm-extract berlin-latest.osm.pbf -p profiles/car.lua
osrm-contract berlin-latest.osrm
osrm-routed berlin-latest.osrm
```

I would like to start a server not only on Berlin dataset, but on a full country dataset. For instance all German country roads. Maybe there is something to do with the contract, but i don't really know what king of .osrm i should put as argument to tell it to use a larger dataset that would be the combination of several dataset.

I think the answer should be really obvious when we know it, but it still feel a bit wooly.

Thank you.

Comment: Um, well, just run it on a larger extract? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: I mean i would like to use an osrm server on a custom dataset. Like maybe some parts of france, and then some parts of germany etc. Then do I have to download the full Europe extract in order to have some part of some different countries? Or maybe i can just download only the useful datasets and do something like packing together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to an [OSRM issue](https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/issues/3001) it is not possible to merge `.osrm` files. However you can merge multiple `PBF` files before generating your `.osrm` files.

Merging of OSM XML or PBF files can be done with [osmium](http://osmcode.org/osmium-tool/):

`osmium merge file1.osm.pbf file2.osm.pbf -o merged.osm.pbf`.

Or with [osmosis](https://github.com/openstreetmap/osmosis):

`osmosis --rb file1.osm.pbf --rb file2.osm.pbf --m --wb merged.osm.pbf`

Comment: Oh, ok, That sound nice, thank you very much. That was what i was looking for.

Comment: Did this tool doing dedublication of data? For example Russia is listed under both Asia and Europe, and if i want combine all region of Russia with Europe, i need to combine 2 PBF file: russia-latest.pbf and europe-latest.pbf. Both of it contain Central Federal District. Did it included in result as single entry?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't answer that. Try it yourself or ask the OSRM developers, if there are any left.

Comment: @scai, can you kindly tell me if this answer will work in my case: I have osrm server set up on ngnix, and i want to add one more country to it, should i do this. Previously i would create separate systemd services for both countries. Please do reply.

Comment: @M_S_N Unfortunately I can't answer this question since I've never run a OSRM server so far.

Answer (score 0):

```
wget http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/germany-latest.osm.pbf

osrm-extract germany-latest.osm.pbf -p profiles/car.lua
osrm-contract germany-latest.osrm
osrm-routed germany-latest.osrm
```

Should work, but please note it will require around 16GB of RAM and probably a similar amount of disk space.

**EDIT:**

After clarification what you will need to do is merge the  `.osm.pbf` files using the [`osmium` tool](https://github.com/osmcode/osmium-tool).

```
./osmium merge first.osm.pbf second.osm.pbf third.osm.pbf -o result.osm.pbf
```

Comment: You are right, my example was really bad because i did not realize there was a file for full germany. Let me rephrase it.. Well, i actualy would like to pick some datasets (let's say : http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/france/champagne-ardenne.html, then http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/france/auvergne.html and finally http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/italy/centro.html)

Then, do I have to download the full europe map, or can i just get those three, and pack it together in order to only use what i will need.